# npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, npm, mup

Getting error:

> npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0 while running MUP.

Answer (score 1):

Update meteor using 'meteor update' command to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Is there any solution without meteor update. Thanks